# How to remove leading characters and the query character with a regular expression in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am using `preg_replace()` and a regular expression to remove all characters before a hyphen (-). I'd like to update the expression to also remove the hyphen itself. The full line of code is shown below in context.

```
$item['options']['Size'] = preg_replace('/^[^-]*/', '', $item['options']['Size']);
```

So as it stands let's say I have the below string:

> TEST123-150X200

The current preg_replace function will leave me with:

> -150X200

I'd like to end up with:

> 150X200

Could anyone suggest how I can update the regular_expression to achieve this. Thanks

Comment: Add a hyphen at the end of the pattern. `$item['options']['Size'] = preg_replace('/^[^-]*-/', '', $item['options']['Size']);`.

Comment: What about `substr()` ? `$item['options']['Size'] = substr(preg_replace('/^[^-]*/', '', $item['options']['Size']),1 );` Starting the newly generated string one step further, that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a hyphen at the end of the pattern.

```
$item['options']['Size'] = preg_replace('/^[^-]*-/', '', $item['options']['Size']);
                                                ^
```

This way, the hyphen is matched (=consumed) and will be removed. Note that `[^-]` is a negated character class that matches any character but a `-`. Thus the hyphen was not matched by your original regex.

A non-regex approach:

```
$item['options']['Size'] = ltrim(strstr($item['options']['Size'], '-'),'-');
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/6Tm351)

Comment: Thanks @stribizhev that's a nice approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$item = 'TEST123-150X200'; // string here
echo preg_replace('/^[^-]*-/', '', $item);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers/comments given, you could also use a positive lookbehind and replace this:

```
<?php
$str = "TEST123-150X200";
$regex = '/.*(?<=-)/i';
$item['options']['Size'] = preg_replace($regex, '', $str);
// output: 150X200
?>
```

Alternatively (as described in the comment), start counting from 1:

```
$item['options']['Size'] = substr(preg_replace('/^[^-]*/', '', $item['options']['Size']), 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont think it needs a regex for this...

```
$str = "TEST123-150X200";
var_dump(end(explode("-", $str))); //string(7) "150X200"
var_dump(ltrim(strstr($str, "-"), "-"));//string(7) "150X200"
var_dump(substr(strrchr($str, "-"), 1) );//string(7) "150X200"
```